# Using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client to downloading specific files from a VersionSpec

Tags: c#, tfs, team-project

What I am trying to do is find all .sql scripts pushed into my Test TFS Team Project during a specific timeframe AND then get either a link to view the file or download that copy OUTSIDE of my workspace. So I don't necessary want to get latest. This will be for an application to review all specifically .sql changes executed during a specific timeframe and then I will be comparing those files with a branched environment to determine which .sql where copied and ran against the database.

I am stuck on getting either a link to view the file or downloading the files. The problem I foresee with downloading the files is that I am going to download hundreds of files and what I really will end up doing to viewing each file to determine if I can re-run the .sql script against a different environment outside of Test.

```
 public void GetChangesets(DataTable files,
                           bool excludeManualDatabaseFiles,
                           bool containsExcludedDerictoriesAndFiles)
    {
        // this gets collection-lvl services, in contrast to TfsConfigurationServer (server-lvl)
        Uri serverUri = new Uri("<insert serverUri>");
        var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
        var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        DateTime testDate;
        DateTime.TryParse("2017-07-01", out testDate);

        VersionSpec fromDateVersion = new DateVersionSpec(testDate);
        VersionSpec toDateVersion = new DateVersionSpec(DateTime.Now);

        vcs.QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full);

        string teamProjectName = "<insert team project name>";
        TeamProject[] tps = new TeamProject[]
        {
            vcs.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName)
        };

        DataTable returnedChangesetDetail = new DataTable();
        // Step 1: THIS WORKS
        returnedChangesetDetail.Columns.Add("FileName");
        // Step 2: THIS DOES NOT WORK, this is currently empty !!!!!!
        returnedChangesetDetail.Columns.Add("Uri");


        foreach(TeamProject tp in tps)
        {
            IEnumerable changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(string.Concat("$/", tp.Name, "/Test/SQL"), 
                VersionSpec.Latest,
                deletionId: 0,
                recursion: RecursionType.Full,
                user: null,
                versionFrom: fromDateVersion,
                versionTo: toDateVersion,
                maxCount: int.MaxValue,
                includeChanges: true,
                slotMode: true);



            foreach(Changeset changeset in changesets)
            {

                foreach(Change change in changeset.Changes)
                {
                    string fileName = change.Item.ServerItem;
                    // I think this would be it but its not an accessible link, do I add/remove
                    // something to make this a Uri?
                    //var artifactUrui = change.Item.ArtifactUri; 

                    // Step 1: WORKING
                    lstbxFileNames.Items.Add(fileName);

                 }
            }

        }

    }
```

I hope that the comments explain what I am looking for. This will be an app for a non-dev but tech user to be able to review the changes needed in their environment. They will need to review approx 100 files and I was thinking a Uri would be an easy way for them to see the changes and then later select the files they need while disregarding changes found in Step 1 but determined not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the download URL of the file.

If your TFS version is TFS 2015 or higher, you can use [version control Items REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items#get-a-specific-version) link (Make sure current user has permission to access target files)

Otherwise, you can provide a **button/hyperlink** with Path and version (date) arguments, then download the file (temp file) by using [DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138622(v=vs.120).aspx) method and send the content stream (read content by stream) to client to let user save to local machine in **button/hyperlink click event**.

Comment: What is the server path in this method? I would have thought it was Item.ServerItem but that seems to just throw an invalid file name exception.

Comment: @vfrank66 It is ServerItem, works fine for me. Has this file been deleted? Does the code like this: DownloadFile(changeset.Item.ServerPath, changeset.Item.DeletionId, new DateVersionSpec(changeset.Item.CheckinDate), "D:\\d\\test.cs");?